# Visual Studio 2012: "Navigate To" is suddenly very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've loved Visual Studio's "Navigate To" tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) ever since it was first introduced - rather than navigate through my folder structure I could just find the file or class I needed by name. The key has always been that the lookup was instantaneous - it would show all matching results as quickly as I could type.

Now something has changed and there's almost always a big lag before any results come up - I've measured it as long as 10 seconds sometimes. This is about 5 seconds into a search that has only one result and should have come up instantly:

[image]

That progress bar also jumps around in a bizarre way.

Any ideas what might have changed, or what I might do to get back my speedy old Navigate tool?

Comment: Did you have installed some addin or extensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and deleting everything in c:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\ helped. Now it's quick again.

I've found this soultion [here](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2013/02/21/Visual-Studio-2012-running-slow.aspx).